# Does the environment matter (area outside the box) in tensorflow's object detection algorithm?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am exploring tensorflow's object detection algorithm.

Prior to training I had to mark boxes around my items in the training dataset images. This was fed into training. Does the environment (surroundings) outside of the box marking matter in tensorflow's object detection algorithm? Or is the training based only on the contents inside of the marked box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The training is based on the boxes content only, but during the detection process, the algorithm has to scan all the image.

Consequently, there is no learning of the environment outside the box.
Such algorithms only focus on [detecting specific objects](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2524.pdf), independently from their surrounding environment.

However, tensorflow could be used to apply [contextual object recognition](https://github.com/justinkay/context-rcnn-d2), but it requires additional function such as an attention mechanism.

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know.